# Dynamic topology in sculpt mode causes sculpt to deform on opposite side

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I have been trying to find a way to word this to google or SE search, and I can't find anyone showing this issue. When I sculpt with dynamic topology enabled, the changes that I make to one side of the sculpt cause changes on the other side of the sculpt that I did not intend. In the example below, I used Draw brush on the side facing away from the view. I did not do anything to the side facing toward the view, that all happened on its own. This only happens when dyntopo is enabled. Any ideas how I can prevent this besides just not being able to use dyntopo?

[image: Sculpt with indent on side facing camera, and bulge on other side.]

Comment: Maybe activate the Front Faces Only option, but it should not happen only with Dyntopo... Or please share your file so that we can test?

Comment: @moonboots - This was a new file after a fresh install of Blender 3.5. Literally just started it up and noticed the issue right away. :/ The Front Faces Only option also causes issues with sculpting because any polygon that isn't facing directly at the view has a chance to be ignored, which makes for a very messy sculpt.